# UITableView issue, it scrolls halfway up after updating or inserting a new cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My TableView is doing some kind of auto-scrolling after any kind of updates are applied to it. If I were to append a new element to the array that contains the items which are presented in the UITableView, for some reason my Table View scrolls up somewhat randomly up around 50% up the middle of the contents of the TableView.

Here's the function that deals with updating, not inserting an item into the Table View:

```
func updateLastMessage() {

    var section = msgSections.count - 1
    var row = msgSections[section].msg.count - 1
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()    
}
```

This function above works perfectly, but after I call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` on `self.tableView`, the table view automatically scrolls up 50% of the contents of the Table View. I get exactly the same result if I were to insert an item instead:

```
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Also, if I were to comment out both `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`, there seems to be no effect to the scrolling.

I only know of one hack to somewhat get around this issue by using `setContentOffset` to return the scroll position back to where it was before a message was updated, or a new message is inserted:

```
func updateLastMessage() {
    let currentContentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset

    var section = msgSections.count - 1
    var row = msgSections[section].msg.count - 1
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()

    self.tableView.setContentOffset(currentContentOffset, animated: false)
}
```

This hack doesn't work in my favor, because it scrolls slowly to the top and then jolts back to where it was which looks kind of bad.

Does anyone know exactly what could be the mechanism that's causing the TableView to scroll up so much after any appended item or updated item??

It seems to work perfectly and the animation looks very nice as but only when there aren't any items in the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Never call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:` inside `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`.

The `tableView` will automatically call the necessary reloading of rows at the end of `endUpdates()`.

Just call `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` without any code inside. It'll work.